# Timeline view of TFS work items to aid project tracking

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, scrum

Is there a nice way in TFS to see all the Stories/Tasks I have worked on and what day I committed/closed them out and maybe did associated check-ins for them. I want this because I work on many different client projects and need to track my time in a time sheet and sometimes forget what I did each day if I don't fill my timesheet out daily.

Comment: I'm thinking you want an out of the box solution? Are you adverse to using the APIs and rolling your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of box feature for this. A similar feature request on VSTS User Voice can be found here: [User Activity Stream](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3861158-user-activity-stream).

As an alternative solution, there is an [TFS Timetracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Berichthaus.TfsTimetracker) extension in VSTS Marketplace which you can try to use. This extension will allow you to record the time you spend on every work item and generate a report.

Comment: Have you used this one before https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f6ece95a-4868-4291-9cdc-15ab426680a4?SRC=VSIDE? Any opinions on either one?

Answer (score 1):

I believe TFS is unlikely to enable this capability in the nearest future. 
You can try out time sheet extensions to TFS.

For example, TX Chrono (https://www.teamexpand.com/product/tfs-timesheet) allows to log hours directly from a Work Item tab in TFS and get a work time day-by-day breakdown over the selected period (So you can make a report where you'll see hours spent on a particular WI, how many hours were spent each day, WI current state, etc.)